# Select the last consecutive days SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql

Is it possible, with SOQL only, to select something for a consecutive date? Expect following table(where 2012-01-07 is today):

```
User  LoginDate      Whatever
 1,   2012-01-01,    0
 1,   2012-01-02,    2
 3,   2012-01-03,    0
 4,   2012-01-04,    0
 5,   2012-01-05,    0
 6,   2012-01-06,    5
 1,   2012-01-07,    5
```

Now the query should return "1" for user 1, as the last time the user logged in, there were no consecutive logins before. If we have a table like this:

```
    User  LoginDate      Whatever
     1,   2012-01-01,    0
     1,   2012-01-02,    2
     1,   2012-01-03,    0
     1,   2012-01-04,    0
     1,   2012-01-05,    0
     1,   2012-01-06,    5
     1,   2012-01-07,    5
```

It should return "7", as the user was logged in for 7 consecutive days until today. When the user didn't login yesterday, it should return 0.

I sadly only know the basics of SOQL and have no idea where to read up on this. Does someone have a code sample or a link about this topic, if it is possible at all?

Comment: btw: [soql documentation guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/)

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm this is kinda cool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with only `SOQL`. You will need to do some post-processing in Apex or elsewhere if you want this information. For example if you want the current consecutive logins, you would want something like the below.

```
public static Integer getConsecutiveLogins(Id userId)
{
    Set<Date> loginTimes = new Set<Date>();
    for (LoginHistory login : [SELECT LoginTime FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId = :userId])
    {
        loginTimes.add(login.LoginTime.date());
    }

    Integer consecutiveLogins = 0;
    while (loginTimes.contains(Date.today().addDays(-consecutiveLogins)))
    {
        consecutiveLogins++;
    }
    return consecutiveLogins;
}
```

Comment: Looks good! Thank you. I figured I would need to use a for loop, but your while is really smart.